# Can't get value of dropdown list item using Jqoery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have a drop down list, which is within a pop modal.  The drop-down list looks like this:

```
<select name="EventTypeId" class="form-control formTextBox" id="ddlEventType">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">Assessment</option>
    <option value="2">Single Session</option>
    <option value="3">Group Session</option>
</select>
```

And my jquery looks like this:

```
$("body").on("change", "#ddlEventType", function (e) {
var test = $('#ddlEventType').val();
});
```

It hits the onchange function no problem, but whenever I select an option on the ddl, the test variable is always "", never gets the value.  Can anyone help me with what's going wrong here?  Is it because the ddl is inside a modal popup?  I actually have a ddl in a different modal popup, with the exact same code and it works completely as it should.  There's no conflicting ids on the age either.  Can't figure out why I'm not getting the value.

**UPDATE**

I gave the `ddl` a class name of `ddlEventType`, and changed the jquery to

```
$("body").on("change", "#ddlEventType", function (e) {
var test = $('.ddlEventType').val();
});
```

and for some reason this worked.  Don't get why, but it works and that's all I need.  Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: What is `preventDefaultAction()` method??? Check your console for error

Comment: Function to provide a x-browser safe 'PreventDefault' event. In IE it doesnt have one unless it's the Jquery event wrapper.  I've removed this, but it doesn't make a difference.  I'll removed it from my question, could be confusing people, it's irrelevant.

Comment: First time i heard about this... Now are you sure you don't have more than one element with ID `ddlEventType`? What if you use relevant `this`: `var test = $(this).val();`?!

Comment: Do you add the modal within the select dynamicly?

Comment: @necrofish666. I have provided with two solutions. You can have a try and share thoughts

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
  $(document).on('change','#ddlEventType',function(){
    console.log($(this).val());
  });
```

Are you doing any change to the body. And for `preventDefault` it should be `e.preventDefault();`

Comment: `It hits the onchange function no problem` So this answer won't fix it  EDIT: i missed than you are using `this` which then could be relevant indeed

Comment: I removed the preventDefault method, it isn't really needed, and when I remove it, it doesn't change the fact that I'm not getting the value.

Comment: @A.Wolff - he changed the selector to `$(this)`, which you then suggested in a comment

Comment: @necrofish666 Have you tired removing `body` from the selector?

Answer (score 0):

You can follow the below methods for obtaining the selected value from the select tag using the `onchange()` attribute.

1. First method i have called the `onchange()` directly to the script function.
2. Second Method i have given directly a function to the select tag and then called the function in the script file.

**First Method:**

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
$("#ddlEventType").change(function(){
    alert($(this).val());
});
});
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="EventTypeId" class="form-control formTextBox" id="ddlEventType">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">Assessment</option>
    <option value="2">Single Session</option>
    <option value="3">Group Session</option>
</select>
```

**Second Method:**

```js
function get_value(a)
{
  alert(a);
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<select name="EventTypeId" class="form-control formTextBox" id="ddlEventType" onchange="get_value(this.value)">
    <option value="">Please Select</option>
    <option value="1">Assessment</option>
    <option value="2">Single Session</option>
    <option value="3">Group Session</option>
</select>
```